# I can not redirect with .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried to redirect any thing the user write after domainname/ to the index.php file but it is not working unless i write domainname/index.php/sdsdsdsd => this works but i wanna it without typing index.php.

### This is `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution when i changed

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

To:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```